# How to download PDF by clicking using selenium chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to download pdf from https://www.axisbank.com/interest-rate-on-deposits?cta=homepage-rhs-fd link
following code only open the website and click on download link but i am not able to download pdf  Python code

```
print("Helllo Pratik")
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "D:\\pdf_download", 
"download.prompt_for_download": False, 
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\driver_chrome\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get("https://www.axisbank.com/interest-rate-on-deposits?cta=homepage-rhs-fd")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div/span")
element.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some more information? :-)  -> Why can't you download it? What happens? What do you expect to happen? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the ***Domestic Fixed Deposits*** pdf from the [website](https://www.axisbank.com/interest-rate-on-deposits?cta=homepage-rhs-fd) you need to click on the element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "C:\\Datafiles", 
"download.prompt_for_download": False, 
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True 
})
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.axisbank.com/interest-rate-on-deposits?cta=homepage-rhs-fd")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Domestic Fixed Deposits']//following-sibling::div[1]/span"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: fixed deposit]

Comment: EC name error is EC is any object ?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.